# SFSafariViewController does not reopen a webview inline URL link

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a Webview with inline URL links which are opened with SFSafariViewController, as shown below:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
            NSString *inR = [[inRequest URL] absoluteString];
            NSURL *inReq = [NSURL URLWithString:inR];
            SFSafariViewController *safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:inReq entersReaderIfAvailable:YES];
            safariVC.delegate = self;
            [self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - SFSafariViewController delegate methods
-(void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller didCompleteInitialLoad:(BOOL)didLoadSuccessfully {
    // Load finished

}

-(void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
    // Done button pressed
    NSLog(@"DONE PRESSED!!!");
}
```

When I press the DONE button correctly returns to my Webview. The problem is that if I will press again on the same inline link, it does not open with SFSafariViewController but in Webview which is not what i desire. I tried to force Webview reload in safariViewControllerDidFinish but without success.

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you want to return `NO` at the end of your `if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil)` block?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your prompt assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The code corrected as below (following proposal of **beyowulf**) and now is working OK:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        if ([SFSafariViewController class] != nil) {
            NSString *inR = [[inRequest URL] absoluteString];
            NSURL *inReq = [NSURL URLWithString:inR];
            SFSafariViewController *safariVC = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:inReq entersReaderIfAvailable:YES];
            safariVC.delegate = self;
            [self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:nil];
            return NO;
        } else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

#pragma mark - SFSafariViewController delegate methods
-(void)safariViewController:(SFSafariViewController *)controller didCompleteInitialLoad:(BOOL)didLoadSuccessfully {
    // Load finished
}

-(void)safariViewControllerDidFinish:(SFSafariViewController *)controller {
    // Done button pressed
    NSLog(@"DONE PRESSED!!!");
}
```